# Modules with the same name? AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, module

In AngularJS, why some modules have the same name? Is that because we want to divide a big module into different pieces? If I define a controller in one module, can I directly use that in another module which has the same name? Need any dependency injection?

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS modules do not allow namespacing that would prevent collisions between objects in different modules because an AngularJS app has a single injector that stores name for all modules.